# Where is the best place online to learn Ruby on Rails for a beginner?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am very interested in learning Ruby on Rails, but I am having a hard time finding a good place to learn online. So far, everything I have found is either:

1. **outdated information** - there have been several updates to the language and the framework, which makes these tutorials hard to follow.
2. **too complex** - I am only a beginner. I know some html, css, and c#, but learning Rails is nothing like these.

I'm reaching out to the StackOverflow community in hopes that someone can direct me to place I need to go.

Comment: While @noah-r s answer is a bit obnoxious, he's not wrong. A little research would have garnered you a large list of resources you could have started from. 
My answer below addresses you're implied request for a beginners **gentle** intro to RoR.

Comment: I think Team Treehouse www.teamtreehouse.com and Ruby on Rails Tutorial http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters are great places to learn Ruby. Good luck! Btw, people on S.O. can be rude and disrespectful, just ignore them and many great people will help you on here.

Comment: True – there are rude users. But I don't see any of them here.

Comment: I think I will try the Team Treehouse site out first since it appears to be free :) Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ruby.railstutorial.org and codeschool's rails for zombies course are good intro to RoR, especially if your ruby knowledge is limited.

Answer (score -1):

[Here](http://bit.ly/1b9bDXC) is a great resource that will help you alot. This resource is what taught me almost everything I know about programming.

Comment: That's pretty funny, but I tried the Google route already. I've went to many websites that showed up in Google's search results, but like I said, they were all outdated and too complex for me! Thanks for the laugh though.